# Android: How many ways for getting GPS location

Tags: android, gps

I'm using XPosed for faking gps location. I have faked and tested successfully these two apis:

1. `FusedLocationApi` from `GoogleApiClient`
2. `LocationManager` including two methods: `requestLocationUpdates` and `getLastKnownLocation`

But when I test it on some other apps such as Grab, Uber or Google Map, they still display my location correctly. Are they using different APIs? How can I find that out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) there's an additional API supported by `LocationManager`, called [`requestSingleUpdate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate(java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) that can be used to receive a single location update.

Since both `requestSingleUpdate` and `requestLocationUpdates` use [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) and have multiple prototypes (and thus implementations) please make sure to hook and support them all.

As a side note, there are ways (that require user interaction) to add a *test* `LocationProvider` that can spoof locations through the API. see [this](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/) for example.